# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_aData' of undefined en detalle

Tags: jquery, datatables, undefined

tengo una tabla hecha con **datatables** (tabla_1) la cual me muestra la lista normal, ahí tengo un botón que muestra el detalle, ese botón abre un modal con otro *datatables* (tabla_2), al hacer clic en detalle de tabla_1 me muestra el modal y ahí tengo 2 filas con 1 botón de momento para imprimir en consola los datos y funciona, luego al cerrar el modal y hacer clic en el botón de la fila 2 de tabla_1 me muestra el modal con tabla_2 la cual tiene 3 filas y cada uno con su botón, lo raro viene aquí, hago clic en la segunda y tercera fila y si imprime los datos pero al hacer clic en la primera fila de tabla_2 y me manda el error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_aData' of undefined

tengo esta función en datatables

```
obtener_data_agregar_a_detalle_orden_temp('#dt_detalle_cotizacion',dt_detalle_cotizacion);
```

con esto imprimo los datos

```
    function obtener_data_agregar_a_detalle_orden_temp(tbody,table){
    $(tbody).on('click','a.agregar_orden',function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        //$(table).DataTable().ajax.reload();
        $('#dt_detalle_cotizacion').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        // var data=table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        var data=table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data(); 
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: puedes agregar mas informacion esta muy vaga la pregunta!

Comment: si tienes teamviewer para mostrarte, soy nuevo y no tengo idea como publicar, pero mi error esta ahi, o que informacion faltaria?